# page.php vs index.php in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Let say I have a theme that contains both page.php and index.php. 
I also has a Permalink `http://www.example.com/.../post-type/post-title/` to a post.

Will WordPress use `page.php` first, and then use `index.php` if `page.php` is not found? 
Right now, the URL is leading to `index.php`, which is not what I expected.

Answer (score 4):

This defined Permalink  `http://www.example.com/.../post-type/post-title/` is a post. You do not access `page.php` for this, so use `single.php` or `single-$posttype.php`/`single-post.php`.

**See the [Page Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in an image:**

[image]

Comment: It's always nice to add the source (images, code). I've edited to include this info.

Answer (score 1):

A post is not a page, so it will never pass through `page.php`.

Check out the infographic on [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in the Codex.

According to this page you'll need a `single.php` or even a `single-{posttype-here}.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress uses what you tell it to use in the "Settings", under one of the sub options (Reading, Writing, etc.). You choose to tell it to use a "static page" for the home page or not. If you choose a static page, then you need to assign a page you create to be the home page, which will use the "page.php" template out of the box if that's the template you assign to the page you just created.

You can then go a step further and create your own page templates based off the original "page.php" template.

Look here for more info: [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)